# Is it possible to use miles instead of kilometers in a spatial cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, spatial

I use a last version of the Neo4j database and the [Spatial](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial) extension.

If I use the following query:

```
START n=node:locations('withinDistance:[1.0, 1.0, 10.0]') return n
```

The Neo4j Spatial interprets the value '10.0' as a distance in kilometers.

**How can I force the Spatial to interpret it as miles?**

Answer (score 2):

When querying spatial from cypher providing the distance in km is expected. However you can do some math in the statement:

```
START n=node:locations('withinDistance:[1.0, 1.0, ' + (10 *1.60934)  + ']') return n
```

This should find all the things in a 10 miles distance around lon/lat 1.0/1.0.

Comment: Currently I use exactly the same approach. I just was interested to know if there is a better one. This could open up some other interesting features... But thanks anyway!

Comment: you could factor out the distance in miles as a parameter, e.g. `START n=node:locations('withinDistance:[1.0, 1.0, ' + ({dist} *1.60934)  + ']') return n`. I wonder what interesting feature you are thinking about?

Comment: I simply assumed, that maybe there are some possibilities of the cypher query language, which are unknown for me.